# How to convert Telugu Characters into UTF-8 encoded characters in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I have input character like this ఈ. For this character I need equivalent Hex entity "0C08" like this. Is there any inbuilt function in java for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're getting the bytes in `CP850` encoding, then you're creating a new `String` where you lie that the bytes are `UTF-8`. Why do you lie to the `String` constructor? Why? Your code should be `String value = columnDetails.getColumnName();`.

Comment: I want to convert the given input[what ever format it is in] into UTF-8 encoding format. I tried that code but it is not working.

Comment: i mean to say if ము one charter, I need  equivalent UTF-8 character.

Answer (score 1):

Characters in java are kept in unicode.
So we need to specify encoding when reading/writing from/to
external byte stream.

Note this code should print two the same lines on UTF-8 console:

```
String value = columnDetails.getColumnName();
System.out.println(value); //output with default encoding
System.out.write(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));//output with UTF-8
```

Edit:
If you want hex representation of UTF-8 encoding, then try this:

```
//not optimized
String toHex(byte[] b) {
  String s="";
  for (int i=0; i<b.length; ++i) s+=String.format("%02X",b[i]&0xff);
  return s;
}
System.out.println(toHex("ఈ".getBytes("UTF-8"))); //prints E0B088
```

Edit2: or if you want Unicode (two byte representation)

```
static String toHex(String b) {
String s="";
for (int i=0; i<b.length(); ++i) s+=String.format("%04X",b.charAt(i)&0xffff);
    return s;
}
System.out.println(toHex("ఈ")); //prints 0C08
```

Comment: I have researched a lot but I did not get any inbuilt functions in java. What I did is created a class with known Unicode equivalents of Telugu characters and then formed the words. Thanks all for your help

Comment: A clarification _(this doesn't affect the OP's question, since all Telegu characters are in the BMP):_ Java uses the UTF-16 (formerly UCS-2) encoding for Unicode characters, which is why the `char` primitive data type is 16 bits. A Java `String` can represent all Unicode code points, but a `char` can only represent ones in the BMP in (the range `\u0000`-`\uffff`).

Answer (score 0):

Java strings are UTF-16. To get UTF-8, you write something like:

```
String string = "SomethingInTeluguOrwhatever";
byte[] utf8Bytes = string.getBytes(Charsets.forName("utf-8"));
```

That gets you the UTF-8 values. If you want hex, iterate the bytes and print them in hex.